# Display admob ad at the bottom programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I've read a lot about this topic, but nothing works. I've taken the following code from Android Developers:

```
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();

    // Crear adView.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("MY_UNIT_ID");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    // Buscar RelativeLayout suponiendo que se le ha asignado
    // el atributo android:id="@+id/mainLayout".
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    // Añadirle adView.
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Iniciar una solicitud genérica.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Cargar adView con la solicitud de anuncio.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  } 

@Override
  public void onPause() {
    adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adView.resume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

It shows the ad, but it is not at the bottom of the screen. I've also tried with LayoutParams but anything works.

Answer (score 0):

You can set coordinates manually, ad this code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
    //get display height
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int displayHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

    //get adView height
    int adViewHeight = adView.getHeight();
    int viewStartX = displayHeight = adViewHeight;
    adView.setX(viewStartX);      
}
```

you should get the logic if the code is not 100% I'm writing with my phone